# Лимит div в одной строке и перенос на следующую строку

Tags: html, css

Допустим есть список товаров. Добавление товара на страницу производится с сервера. Для блока с товарами установлен `display:flex`, но как реализовать ограничение для одной строки. Допустим, я хочу чтобы показывало в одной строке только 3 товара и далее выполнялся перенос на след строку.

```css
.content {
  width: 1200px;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
}

.product {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="products">
    <!--Сюда добавляется товар с классом product-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А в остальных строках сколько товаров? Тоже по три или больше? Ну и разметку хотя-бы напишите.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров да тоже 3

Comment: Уменьшите ширину контейнера с товарами. Ну и `flex-wrap:wrap`, для контейнера если не установлен ещё.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Уменьшил, теперь все блоки с товарами стали еще ближе друг к другу ну и  те что не влезли просто выехали за границы `products`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку у Вас ширина .product задана жёстко (width: 150px), то чтобы в каждой строке было только 3 элемента, необходимо жёстко ограничить ширину .products (например, 550px). Ну и сделать перенос (flex-wrap: wrap)

```css
.content {
   width: 1200px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.products {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
   border: 1px solid green;
   width: 550px;
   margin: 15px auto;
}

.product {
   text-align: center;
   width: 150px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 10px;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">   
    <div class="products">
        <div class="product">123</div>
        <div class="product">456</div>
        <div class="product">789</div>
        <div class="product">abc</div>
        <div class="product">def</div>
        <div class="product">ghi</div>
        <div class="product">jkl</div>
        <div class="product">nmo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```